# YouTube Data API Error 403 Insufficient Permission

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-platform, youtube-data-api, google-signin

I'm working on an IOS app using Swift that requires accessing to the user's YouTube subscriptions. After adding all scopes I need on Google Cloud Platform and implementing GoogleSignIn in Firebase. I sign in (GIDSignInButton), then I get the error shown down below after making this request:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&mine=true&key=\(apiKey)&access_token=\(Access_Token)`.

The Access_Token is the one I got after I call:

```
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?){
    user.authentication.accessToken
....}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
 ["error": {
        code = 403;
        errors =     (
                    {
                domain = global;
                message = "Insufficient Permission";
                reason = insufficientPermissions;
            }
        );
        message = "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.";
        status = "PERMISSION_DENIED";
    }]
```

In App Delegate I set this:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and, if I remember correctly, it occurred when my OAuth consent verification status was unverified. What I did to make it work was, in addition to supplying scopes in the Google dashboard, I added them programmatically before signing in.

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload")
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, discard the parameter `key=(apiKey)`; the authorization is based solely on `access_token=(Access_Token)`.

Do note that the access tokens are [short-lived](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#offline). You may issue a HTTPS `GET` request to:

`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=(Access_Token)`

for to see whether your access token is still valid. The response provided would look either as:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
```

or as:

```
{
  "issued_to": "...",
  "audience": "...",
  "scope": "...",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "access_type": "offline"
}
```

Then double-check that you have the required scopes attached to that access token in case it's valid.