# Updating the default broadcast's stream title via YouTube API

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, youtube-data-api, google-apps-script-api

Using the link below, the `title` can be easily updated:

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/update?apix=true`.

I wish to implement the same using the YouTube API in Google Apps Script. The code below works successfully, but rather than updating it creates a new stream.

The difference is the link above did not require `scheduledStartTime`. But the API requires it. And when `scheduledStartTime` is given, it creates a new broadcast rather than updating the original one. If `scheduledStartTime` is assigned `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` it acts as if `scheduledStartTime` is not taken into account.

What value to be assigned so that it updates the default broadcast stream rather than updating one.
Or there is there anything else I am missing to complete the update process?

Here is my code:

```
Logger.log('Starting');
service = getService();
if (service.hasAccess()) {

//Fetch the LiveBroadcast Title and Description Details
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?broadcastStatus=upcoming&broadcastType=all";
var parameters = {'headers' : {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()}};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,parameters);
var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
//Logger.log(result);
var resource = result.items[0];

//Edit the LiveBroadcast Title and Description Details scheduledStartTime
var title = "as per today";
var description = "new desc check";
var scheduledStartTime ='1970-01-01T00:00:00Z';
var privacyStatus = 'public';
    
//var privacyStatus = 'unlisted';
//var scheduledStartTime = '2020-10-26T04:08:00Z';

data = { 
  'id' : 'MDaEvnSioI', 
  'status' : { 'privacyStatus' : 'public' , 'selfDeclaredMadeForKids' : false},
  'snippet' : { 'title' : title , 'description' : description , 'scheduledStartTime' : scheduledStartTime }
};
    
//Update the LiveBroadcast 
Logger.log("--");
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
Logger.log(jsondata);
    
    
var options =  {
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()        
  },
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'method' : 'post',
  'payload': jsondata,
  'muteHttpExceptions':true
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
Logger.log('service has access...!!');
```

Comment: wonderful, the solution u mentioned worked! Accepted... ❤

Comment: I have one question related to it... the tokens in youtube expire in 1 hour (3600secs), 
I need to run this script twice daily. How to automatically get new token before running the script?

Comment: For to answer concretely to your question, I would need to see the function `getService`. In any case, here is the official doc with respect to [how to refresh an access token](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#offline),

Comment: If you're using [OAuth2 for Apps Script](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2), then see the [Service_html](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/docs/Service_.html) for the function `refresh()`.

Comment: But since you use `hasAccess`, then you shouldn't do anything, because the same doc says that: *`hasAccess() → {boolean}` Determines if the service has access (has been authorized and hasn't expired). If offline access was granted and the previous token has expired this method attempts to generate a new token.*

Comment: Yes, i am using above mentioned library for OAuth. 

Given offline access. but its not refreshing automatically

Comment: Can you check the version of the library you're using? If you'll look into the newest one, into [Service.js](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/src/Service.js), you'll see that indeed the `hasAccess` function does refresh the access token by calling the `refresh` function. If that token cannot be refreshed then `hasAccess` returns `false`.

Comment: its the latest version 38. 

access_type is already defined as "offline" for refresh tokens. but it I dont know why it only issues access_type as  "online"... is there any reason why it happens? (already set approval_prompt as force...)

Comment: I'd recommend to post a new question that'll include your `getService` code (editing out any credentials data, of course). My best guess is that your access type was set to `online` at the time of the initial OAuth flow.

Comment: The API allows you to query the info attached to any of your access tokens. That info includes the `access_type` of the token. See [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64183397/8327971) for the procedure of querying that info.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I had to revoke access to application from Google Account Settings (accounts.google.com). When re-authorized, refresh token appeared!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only what to update a broadcast's `title` and `description` properties, then according to the official docs you may simply use the [`Videos.update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) API endpoint:

> [**`snippet.title`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#snippet.title) (string)
> The broadcast's title. Note that the broadcast represents exactly one YouTube video. You can set this field by modifying the broadcast resource or by setting the [`title`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.title) field of the corresponding video resource.
>
> [**`snippet.description`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#snippet.description) (string)
> The broadcast's description. As with the `title`, you can set this field by modifying the broadcast resource or by setting the [`description`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.description) field of the corresponding video resource.

For to achieve that, do modify your code as follows:

```
// First step: obtain the video's 'categoryId'

var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet&fields=items/snippet/categoryId&id=MDaEvnSioI";

var options = {
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
  }
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var categoryId = result.items[0].snippet.categoryId;

// Second step: update the video's 'title' and 'description',
// using its 'categoryId' obtained above

var url2 = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet";

var data2 = {
  'id': 'MDaEvnSioI',
  'snippet': {
    'title': title,
    'description': description,
    'categoryId': categoryId
  }
};

var options2 =  {
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()        
  },
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload': JSON.stringify(data2),
  'method': 'put'
};

var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options2);
```

Please note that updating a video's `title` and `description` is a two-step process, because, as per the official docs, when invoking the `Videos.update` endpoint on the video's `snippet` object, [one need to pass](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update#request-body) that video's [`categoryId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.categoryId) property to the endpoint as well.

Thus, first query the video's current `categoryId` property using the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint, and only after that invoke `Videos.update`.

Also note that the code above is simplified quite much, since it does not handle the errors that may be returned by these API calls.

---

For what concerns your issue (quote):

> [...] And when scheduledStartTime is given, it creates a new broadcast rather than updating the original one.

please acknowledge that calling for the API on the URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts`

as you do with your code, you're actually invoking the [`LiveBroadcasts.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert) API endpoint instead of the [`LiveBroadcasts.update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/update), as you actually expect.

This happens to be so because both these API endpoints have the same URL; the thing that differentiates the two is the HTTP method that invokes each: `POST` for the former and `PUT` for the latter.

Since your second call to [`UrlFetchApp.fetch`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) does specify explicitly the `method` to be `POST`, you're really calling for `LiveBroadcasts.insert` endpoint and not for `LiveBroadcasts.update`.