# Like a video in Node.js via Youtube API v3

Tags: node.js, api, post, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to let logged in users (they log via google oAuth2 with Youtube permissions), to like videos by clicking the thumbsup button, which simply fires a function.
Project is in Node.js

The **function** is this:

```
const likeVideo = () => {
  if (session){
      let token = JSON.stringify(session.token, null, 2)
      let u = `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=${vidId}&rating=like&key=${apiKey}`
    
      fetch(u, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        }).then(responseJson => {
          console.log(responseJson)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
      });

    }
 }
```

`session` is true, `token` and all other variables are good.

The responseJson logs this:

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: Gunzip {
      _writeState: [Uint32Array],
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      bytesWritten: 0,
      _handle: [Zlib],
      _outBuffer: <Buffer 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 2f 6a 73 6f 6e 3b 63 68 61 72 73 65 74 3d 75 74 66 2d 38 3b 62 61 73 65 36 34 2c 65 79 4a 32 5a 58 4a ... 16334 more bytes>,
      _outOffset: 0,
      _chunkSize: 16384,
      _defaultFlushFlag: 2,
      _finishFlushFlag: 2,
      _defaultFullFlushFlag: 3,
      _info: undefined,
      _maxOutputLength: 4294967296,
      _level: -1,
      _strategy: 0,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null,
      [Symbol(kError)]: null
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=xxxxxxxxxxx&rating=like&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    status: 403,
    statusText: 'Forbidden',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

I followed the official google documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate , the only thing missing in my code I think is what you can find in the curl example as `--compressed`.
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your access token still valid? Check that by the method shown by [one answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64183397/8327971). If your access token is OK, then double-check that its scope matches at least one of [those required](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate#auth) by the API endpoint you're invoking.

Comment: Thanks I was using /youtube.readonly scope, that's why subscriptions worked fine but rating didn't, as i removed .readonly it works