# How to retrieve popular videos from all channels a CMS account manages?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I want to get a list of videos sorted by view count from all channels a CMS account manages.

So I tried query below on query on 'Try this api' page:

```
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&forContentOwner=true&maxResults=25&onBehalfOfContentOwner=DqqiEGtVcyLMIocnDuJHoA&order=viewCount&type=video&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

And its response is:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "youtube.api.v3.SearchListResponse.Error",
        "reason": "ERROR_UNSPECIFIED"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try to isue the very same `curl` command at a command line prompt window (if you're at a Windows machine) or, respectively, within a terminal window at a shell prompt (when you're at a Linux machine). Don't forget to pass on a valid access token. The API key parameter `key` is not required when using access tokens; thus you may and should remove that from the invoking URL.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I tried as what you mentioned, but it results the same.

Comment: Make sure your access token is *valid*. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64183397/8327971) how to double-check its validity.

Comment: On the other hand, [`forContentOwner`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forContentOwner) has the following spec: *This parameter can only be used in a properly authorized request, and it is intended exclusively for YouTube content partners.* Thus, a legitimate question arise: *are you a YouTube content partner?*

Comment: The same requirement applies to [`onBehalfOfContentOwner`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#onBehalfOfContentOwner).