# YouTube Data API called using curl: The request is missing a valid API key

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm getting a fresh access token and I follow the command in the terminal:

```bash
curl \
-H "[AUTH_TOKEN]" \
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&forMine=true&maxResults=50' -i
```

After that I get the error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

A similar result is due to sending a team to the *Postman* program.

The access token is valid.
Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official specification](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#curl-examples), you'll have to issue the following `curl` command instead:

```bash
$ curl \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&forMine=true&maxResults=50'
```

Please note the different *syntax* above w.r.t. the argument of `curl`'s option `-H`; `$ACCESS_TOKEN` is your (valid!) access token.

Comment: The exact command CURL looks like this.
 
curl -H "Authorization: bearer 1************AIm5kNNqw361g" https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&forMine=true&maxResults=50 -i

Token is correct.

Comment: My `curl` command above is *as correct and exact as it needs to be*. You may interpret (at your will) `$ACCESS_TOKEN` as an environment variable, letting the shell do the variable expansion; otherwise you yourself may do the access token expansion in place.

Comment: On the other hand, you also may add extra command line options to `curl` as you need, according to your programming context.

Comment: I used your code and also got an error

{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}

Comment: @Andrii: That error message is due to having passed on to the API an *invalid* access token: just issue `curl` with `-H 'Authorization: Bearer foobar'` to reproduce that error response.

Comment: @Andrii: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64183397/8327971) how to double-check the validity of an access token.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with the apiKey in the query string as `key=[APIKEY]`.

`curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=[APIKEY]'`